# Show 404 page with redirecting to www only

Tags: .htaccess

I want to change the 404 error. I redirected the 404 error page to a custom one, without redirecting the URL itself. This works, see (http://www.gincher.net/not.exist).
I'm using Google PageSpeed, which works only when the user enters from `www`. So I add a redirect to add a `www`, which works for me.

The problem starts when I combine them (http://gincher.net/not.exist). It gives this error:

> **Moved Permanently**
>
> The document has moved here (gincher.net/not.exist).
>
> Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while
>   trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Here is my HTACCESS code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^gincher.net$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.gincher.net$1 [R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /error.php [L]
```

Please advice!

Comment: what does redirect to www mean in your question? Are you talking about redirecting to the root-domain? Ex: www.stackoverflow.com would be the root of this site.

Comment: @john redirect to `www` means that when you'll enter to gincher.net it will redirect you to **www**.gincher.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you're redefining the behaviour of `ErrorDocument`.

Your rule

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /error.php [L]
```

is the same as

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php
```

Then, you still have a syntax error in your first rule.
Replace your current code by this one

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^gincher\.net$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.gincher.net/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Note: you also have the possibility to write the same rule without hard-coding your domain name

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```